# ChromaDB query filtering by documents

Tags: python, chromadb

Can I run a query among a supplied list of documents, for example, by adding something like "where documents in supplied_doc_list"? I know those documents are in the collection. I kept track of them when I added them. Alternatively, is there a way to filter based on docID. As another alternative, can I create a subset of the collection for those documents, and run a query in that subset of collection? Thanks a lot!

```
results = collection.query(
    query_texts=["Doc1", "Doc2"],    
    n_results=1

)
```